# About SELECT * FROM FINAL/OLD/NEW Table

Tags: sql

I recently only aware of these types of table - FINAL/OLD/NEW. However, when I search online, there is no explanation on what it does. Can anyone provide some explanation? In what cases that these tables can or cannot be used.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Didn't you see the red box recommending that you add this when posting a SQL question?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a reference to DB2 output tables when executing a DML statement.  The behavior looks similar to the MERGE statement in SQL Server or when the INSERTED/DELETED output tables are used in trigger statements.

```
>>-+-FINAL TABLE--(INSERT statement)---------------+------------>
   +-+-FINAL-+--TABLE--(searched UPDATE statement)-+   
   | '-OLD---'                                     |   
   +-OLD TABLE--(searched DELETE statement)--------+   
   '-FINAL TABLE--(MERGE statement)----------------'   

>--+--------------------+--------------------------------------><
   '-correlation-clause-'
```

**FINAL TABLE**

Specifies that the rows of the intermediate result table represent the set of rows that are changed by the SQL data change statement as they appear at the completion of the SQL data change statement. If there are AFTER triggers that result in further operations on the table that is the target of the SQL data change statement, an error is returned. If the target of the SQL data change statement is a view that is defined with an INSTEAD OF trigger for the type of data change, an error is returned.

**OLD TABLE**

The rows of the intermediate result table represent the set of affected rows as they exist prior to the application of the SQL data change statement.

[Sourced from IBM Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_tablereference.dita)

This article describes in more detail the usage.  The FINAL TABLE select is wrapped around a change statement and allows you to select from the intermediate result table:

```
SELECT * FROM FINAL TABLE (INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (COL1, COL2) VALUES (VALUE1, VALUE2))
```

[Syntax Example](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/db2luw/selecting-from-an-insert-update-delete-statement-7239)

** I do not typically work in DB2 and have not verified the SQL provided here **

Comment: In the case where I insert a records into the table. What does SELECT * FROM FINAL TABLE return?