# DB2 Select and insert based on bound parameters in php script

Tags: php, sql, db2

I've been trying to slowly migrate a script that selects data, and inserts based on bound parameters into another table from mysql to db2.

I have most of it migrated, but this main portion is still failing to insert. My select is working, returning exactly what I expect. However, something is going wrong in the bit where I create the array or parameter values. I"m simply trying to iterate through the selected value rows and insert the values into a matching table.

I'm I using odbc_fetch_array incorrectly, or does it look like something's wrong with my bound parameters?

```
//Main query to select data
$data = "
  SELECT  
      u.extension
      , sum(duration) as total_talk_time_seconds
      , round(sum(duration) / 60,2) as total_talk_time_minutes
      , sum(case when legtype1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as total_outbound

  from SESSION a
    join call_summary b
      on a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
    inner join system_USERS u
      on u.EXTENSION = CALLINGPARTYNO or u.EXTENSION = FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO
  group by extension,u.user_id" or die(db2_conn_error($DB2Conn));


$stmt = "
  INSERT into daily_call_totals
    (extension,
    total_talk_time_seconds,
    total_talk_time_minutes,
    total_outbound)
  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)" or die(db2_conn_error($DB2Conn));

//create array for binding
$content = [];

$mainResult = odbc_exec($DB2Conn, $data);
while ($d = odbc_fetch_array($mainResult)) {

  $prepInsert = odbc_prepare($DB2Conn, $stmt);

  //for each row, bind param. This is to ensure we get the correct number of records whether they're being inserted or updated for duplicates
  $values = [
      $d['extension'],
      $d['total_talk_time_seconds'],
      $d['total_talk_time_minutes'],
      $d['total_outbound']];

  // Store the current row
  $content[] = $d;

  if($prepInsert){
      $result = odbc_execute($prepInsert,$values);
      if($result){
        print "successfully added record";
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...this is from DB2 to DB2?  DB2 (like every RDBMS I'm aware of) allows you to `INSERT <data> FROM SELECT`, which is faster and would involve no bound parameters.  If you need to know which rows were inserted, you want the [`FINAL TABLE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27161747/about-select-from-final-old-new-table) feature.  If you need to perform some filtering first, though, obviously this won't work.  Otherwise, we need to have a better idea of what the actual problem is.  Are you getting an error?  No results?  Are you even getting rows to add?

Comment: So, I'm getting the rows, but when it gets to the part to insert the script just ends with no error thrown but when I select from the table it's empty showing no results were inserted

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I think i resolved it by doing INSERT INTO...SELECT actually but my only hang up is I have a duplicate key constraint on two columns because this job runs throughout the day but should only create one record per day for each user. Maybe I can update it to use Merge

Comment: then yes, `MERGE` would be the answer.

Comment: What are the two columns with dup key constraint? Are they in the append query?

Comment: ```extension``` and ```date_of_report``` are the two columns, I simply removed the date column from my query above @Parfait

Comment: What is the error you receive or undesired results? *something is going wrong* ... is not helpful for us. Check server log files if needed.

Comment: @Parfait that was the issue, I was getting no errors in the terminal or the logs, it just wasn't inserting. But I fixed it by doing the insert into/select from and I'm making it into a merge statement now for the duplicate key issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned consider an `INSERT...SELECT` and avoid the looped `INSERT...VALUES`. In fact, even consider the ANSI version (i.e., compliant in all SQL-supported DBMS's) of avoiding duplicates using the `NOT EXISTS` clause. But this will only run **one** action and not conditionally two actions.

Below can be run **anytime** and only unique pairings of *date_of_report* and *extension* will be appended, ignoring matches. Be sure to replace *date_of_report* and *my_report_date_column* for actual columns as you never explicitly do so in aggregate query.

```sql
INSERT into daily_call_totals
        (date_of_report,                                  -- UPDATE COLUMN
         extension,
         total_talk_time_seconds,
         total_talk_time_minutes,
         total_outbound)
SELECT
      my_report_date_column,                              -- UPDATE COLUMN
      u.extension
      , sum(duration) as total_talk_time_seconds
      , round(sum(duration) / 60,2) as total_talk_time_minutes
      , sum(case when legtype1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as total_outbound

FROM SESSION a
JOIN call_summary b
  ON a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
JOIN system_USERS u
  ON u.EXTENSION = CALLINGPARTYNO or u.EXTENSION = FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT sub.date_of_report, sub.extension
    FROM daily_call_totals sub
    WHERE sub.date_of_report = my_report_date_column     -- UPDATE COLUMN
      AND sub.extension = u.extension)
GROUP BY my_report_date_column, extension, u.user_id     -- UPDATE COLUMN
```

---

Now if you want to run two actions conditionally: 1) update existing values OR 2) insert new values, then use DB2's [`MERGE`](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/merge?lang=en) (available in some but not all RDBMS's):

```sql
MERGE INTO daily_call_totals AS d
USING
   (SELECT
          my_report_date_column,                              -- UPDATE COLUMN
          u.extension
          , sum(duration) as total_talk_time_seconds
          , round(sum(duration) / 60,2) as total_talk_time_minutes
          , sum(case when legtype1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as total_outbound

    FROM SESSION a
    JOIN call_summary b
      ON a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
    JOIN system_USERS u
      ON u.EXTENSION = CALLINGPARTYNO or u.EXTENSION = FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO
    GROUP BY my_report_date_column, extension, u.user_id     -- UPDATE COLUMN
   ) AS q
ON (d.date_of_report = q.my_report_date_column               -- UPDATE COLUMN
    AND d.extension = q.extension)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET d.total_talk_time_seconds = q.total_talk_time_seconds,
                d.total_talk_time_minutes = q.total_talk_time_minutes,
                d.total_outbound = q.total_outbound            
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (date_of_report,                                 -- UPDATE COLUMN
             extension,
             total_talk_time_seconds,
             total_talk_time_minutes,
             total_outbound)
     VALUES (q.my_report_date_column,                        -- UPDATE COLUMN
             q.extension
             q.total_talk_time_seconds
             q.total_talk_time_minutes
             q.total_outbound);
```

Comment: This is a perfect usage, as far as the merge. Trying this now

Comment: Great to hear! Glad to help.